# modifying a vim function constantly giving me: "Not enough arguments for function"

Tags: vim

I have this function:

```
function! Find(name)
  let l:list=system("find . -name '".a:name."' | perl -ne 'print \"$.\\t$_\"'")
  let l:num=strlen(substitute(l:list, "[^\n]", "", "g"))
  if l:num < 1
    echo "'".a:name."' not found"
    return
  endif
  if l:num != 1
    echo l:list
    let l:input=input("Which ? (CR=nothing)\n")
    if strlen(l:input)==0
      return
    endif
    if strlen(substitute(l:input, "[0-9]", "", "g"))>0
      echo "Not a number"
      return
    endif
    if l:input<1 || l:input>l:num
      echo "Out of range"
      return
    endif
    let l:line=matchstr("\n".l:list, "\n".l:input."\t[^\n]*")
  else
    let l:line=l:list
  endif
  let l:line=substitute(l:line, "^[^\t]*\t./", "", "")
  execute ":e ".l:line
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Find :call Find("<args>")
```

When I try adding a parameter, so the declaration becomes `function! Find(name, search_dir)`, it always tells me i don't have enough parameters when I call the function in vim using `:Find x y`(where as `Find: x` would work when ther was only 1 parameter in the function declaration.

Any idea how I can add multiple parameters?

The end goal is to have a Find function that finds in a specified subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An addition to @Peter Rincker answer: you should never use `"<args>"` if you want to pass parameter to a function as there is already a builtins `<q-args>` and `<f-args>` which do not need additional quoting and do not introduce a possibility of code injection (try `Find ".string(g:)."` with your code). First will pass all parameters as one item, second will produce a list of parameters suitable for a function call:

```
command -nargs=+ Find :call Find(<f-args>)
```

Another things to consider:

1. (system() call) Never pass user input to shell as-is, use `shellescape(str, 1)`. You may have unexpected problems here.
2. `strlen(substitute(l:input, "[0-9]", "", "g"))>0` condition is equivalent to `input=~#'\D'`, but is much bigger.
3. You don't need to specify `l:`: it is the default scope inside functions.
4. There is a built-in `glob()` function: the whole `system()` line can be replaced with

   ```
   join(map(split(glob('./*'.escape(a:name, '\`*[]?').'*'), "\n"), 'v:key."\t".v:val'), "\n")
   ```
5. Don't forget to escape everything you execute: `execute ":e ".l:line` should be written as `execute "e" fnameescape(line)` (it is the third place where code injection is possible in such a simple code snippet!).
6. It is better to use lists here, in this case you don't need to use something to add line numbers:

   ```
   function s:Find(name)
       let list=split(glob('./*'.fnameescape(a:name).'*'), "\n")
       if empty(list)
           echo string(a:name) "not found"
           return
       endif
       let num=len(list)
       if num>1
           echo map(copy(list), 'v:key."\t".v:val')
           let input=input("Which?")
           if empty(input)
               return
           elseif input=~#'\D'
               echo "Not a number"
               return
           elseif input<1 || input>num
               echo "Out of range"
               return
           endif
           let line=list[input]
        else
           let line=list[0]
        endif
        execute "e" fnameescape(line)
    endfunction
    command! -nargs=1 Find :call Find(<f-args)
   ```
7. Neither you nor me handle the situation where filename that matches pattern contains a newline. I know how to handle this (you can see my [vim-fileutils](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3325) plugin (deprecated) or [os.listdir](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor/src/81d5f9a2c45d/plugin/frawor/os.vim#cl-134) function of [os](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor/src/default/plugin/frawor/os.vim) module of [frawor](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/frawor) plugin (in alpha stage, not posted to vim.org)). I don't think such situation is likely, so just remember that it is possible.

Comment: This is a great example of many of the small things one must do when writing a proper vim function/command. I really appreciate the `escape()` that you use for `glob()`. Thank you.

Comment: @Peter Rincker I just rechecked it and found that it is incomplete: things like `glob('%')` expand to a current file name. It does not matter here (`%` is preceded by something and thus is not expanded), but I guess `fnameescape()` is safer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `-nargs=1` to `-nargs=+`. This will mean you have to have arguments but does not specify a number. I suggest you change your `Find` function to `Find(...)` and use `a:0` get the number of arguments to error out if an invalid number of arguments are used.

Example function and command with multiple parameters:

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=dir Find call Find(<f-args>)
fun! Find(name, ...)
  let dir = getcwd()
  if a:0 == 1
    let dir = getcwd() . '/' . (a:1 =~ '[/\\]$' ? a:1 : a:1 . '/')
  elseif a:0 != 0
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echo "Must supply 1 or 2 arguments"
    echohl NONE
  endif
  let &efm = "%f"
  cexpr []
  caddexpr split(glob(dir . '**/*' . escape(a:name, '\`*[]?') . '*'), '\n')
  copen
  aug Find
    au!
    au BufLeave <buffer> ccl|aug! Find
  aug END
endfun
```

For more help

```
:h :command-nargs
:h ...
```

**Edit**
Added example of function that excepts multiple parameters as suggest by @ZyX.

Comment: You have not explained how function will get multiple values in this case. Error for invalid number of arguments will be thrown by vim, but he needs a way to actually path this [in]valid number.

Comment: Thank you @ZyX. I have added an example command and function to better describe the solution.